# How to safely cast generic wildcard "?" to known type parameter in Java?

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-parameter

How to safely cast `Class<?>` (returned by `Class.forName()`) to `Class<Annotation>` without issuing "Unchecked cast" warning?

```
    private static Class<? extends Annotation> getAnnotation() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName("java.lang.annotation.Retention");
        if (!Annotation.class.isAssignableFrom(loadedClass)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("@Retention is expected to be an annotation.");
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass = (Class<? extends Annotation>) loadedClass;
        return annotationClass;
    }
```

Comment: You can't. When you're using reflection, almost everything you do is unsafe. Some of those things might generate compiler warnings, if enabled. So I guess you can: Disable the warning globally as a compiler option.

Comment: @Sweeper this is incorrect in two ways. See my answer. You CAN check that `loadedClass` is a subclass of Annotation, AND provided the snippet isn't an oversimplification and the type is known at write time, you can get a fully generified and typesafe expression representing the Class object.

Comment: Haha, I was thinking too narrowly. I meant "...of doing this _cast_" and I was referring to OP's code snippet of him casting to `Class<? extends Annotation>`. I misread the part where they said they want `Class<Annotation>`. @rzwitserloot

Comment: @Sweeper the quesiton was also edited, it DID cast to `Class<Annotation>` where it's now casting to `Class<? extends Annotation>`

Answer (score 7):

Multiple misconceptions need to be explained before delving into the answer.

### You're using the wrong variance

> `final Class<Annotation> annotationClass = (Class<Annotation>) loadedClass;`

This is actually illegal in any case. Try it:

```
Class<Number> n = Integer.class;
```

That won't compile.

Generics are **invariant**. It means that within the `<>`, you can't use a supertype as a standin for a subtype or vice versa.

Normal java (when `<>` are not involved) is **covariant**. Any subtype is a stand-in for one of its supertypes. This:

```
Number n = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

is perfectly legal java. But in generics world it isn't. If you want it to be, then, you have to opt into it: `X extends Y` is how you opt into covariance, and `X super Y` is how you opt into contravariance (contravariance is as if `Integer i = new Number();` was legal - a SUPERtype can stand in for a subtype).

This is all because that's just how the universe ends up working out. If generics were naturally covariant, this would compile:

```
List<Integer> listOfInts = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> listOfNums = listOfInts;
listOfNums.add(Double.valueOf(1.0));
int i = listOfInts.get(0);
```

but, follow along with your own eyes and you realize that code is a walking type violation. It shoves a non-integer into a list of integers. That's why opting into covariance or contravariances closes doors. If you opt into covariance, **the add method is disabled** *1:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //legal
list.add(Integer.valueOf(5)); // will not compile
```

similarly, if you opt into contravariance, add works great, but **`get` is disabled**. 'disabled' in the type system sense: You can call it. But the expression `list.get(i)` would be of type Object:

```
List<? super Integer> list = new ArrayList<Number>(); // legal
list.add(Integer.valueOf(5)); // legal
Integer i = list.get(0); // won't compile
Object o = list.get(0); // this will.
```

With classes, where 'write' is not exactly clear, it's harder to see why `Class<Annotation> c = SomeSpecificAnno.class;` should fail to compile, but it does, so, that's important realization one.

### Why are you using reflection here?

You can make class literals in java. This works great:

```
Class<? extends Number> c = Integer.class;
```

That's real java: You can stick `.class` at the end of any type and that will be an expression of type `java.lang.Class`, in fact, it's of type `Class<TheExactThing>`. So:

```
private static Class<? extends Annotation> getAnnotationType() {
    return Retention.class;
}
```

works and compiles fantastically. I had to update the return type because as I explained above, returning the instance of `j.l.Class` that represents the `Retention` annotation for a method that is specced to return `Class<Annotation>` is as **broken** as returning an integer from a method that is specced to return a string.

### The answer

If your code example is using `java.lang.annotation.Retention` as a stand-in, but your actual string here is a dynamic value that you do not know at compile time, the `return Retention.class;` option is off the table, then:

```
private static Class<? extends Annotation> getAnnotationType(String fqn) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return Class.forName(fqn).asSubclass(Annotation.class);
}
```

Again, do not use reflection unless there is no other way, and if you have the class in a string constant, generally you do not need reflection.

*1 ) You *can* call add, but only with a null literal; `list.add(null);` compiles, because null is trivially a valid value for any type. However, that's not particularly useful, of course.

Comment: Your quote from the question is not correct anymore as the question was edited since.  It's not making anything you say incorrect, but might be misleading. I just realized the edit myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Due to type erasure, generic type information is not accessible anymore at runtime. This means: `Class<?>` and `Class<? extends Annotation>` are indistinguishable at runtime - so you cannot do a runtime check to make the unchecked cast a checked one.

This means: you have to live with the warning (mind: a warning is not an error, it just means "this is problemattic, make sure you know what you're doing!).

Comment: This is misleading. See my answer - what OP wants is absolutely doable, with no warnings, and no hackery.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I did read your answer and I agree. I ahve to admit, I did not put much effort into understanding the semantics of the code and was only looking at the syntax. Your answer is superior if the code is the actual code - but I'd like to keep mine here in case the question only contains a minimal example that got a bit TOO minimal and the actual case isn't that simple.

Comment: The final part of my answer explains how to do the job if it's not that simple: Use the API and voila, warning poofs out of existence. That API will in fact (at runtime) check your assertion and will throw it it fails, which is why the warning goes away. That warning is all about: Hey, _NO_ exception is going to occur in the places you'd expect it to.